# How to get an MenuItem by id

Tags: android, menuitem

I have my menuItem on my res/menu/student_marks.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".StudentMarks" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_selected_year"
        android:title="@string/action_selected_year"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        style="@style/AppTheme" />
</menu>
```

Now i need for this item to set a title.in a specific part of my app.
I can work with a specific item in this method:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

the problem is that i need the item 'action_selected_year' without of this method but in another part of my program.
 I don't have idea how to get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Menu optionsMenu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       //  store the menu to var when creating options menu
       optionsMenu = menu;
    }
```

example: change icon on first menuItem (optionsMenu should be != null)

```
optionsMenu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_green));
```

Comment: Perfect,  save the reference of the menu inside of the activity variable, allow to me a perfect control on the menu object. Thank you.

Comment: That does not get the menu item by ID. That simply returns the first menu item.

Comment: You can call findItem() and pass the id you're looking for, instead of calling getItem(0).

Answer (score 46):

```
Menu optionsMenu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   //  store the menu to var when creating options menu
   optionsMenu = menu;
}
```

And to get a menu item:

```
MenuItem item = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id. action_selected_year);
```

Comment: You can also retrieve the menu directly from your toolbar (if it's a toolbar from layout): 
Make sure your toolbar have an id in your layout and retrieve it thanks to KTX or to ViewBinding. Let's say we are using ViewBinding, it looks like: 
"viewBinding.my_toolbar_id.menu.findItem(id_of_my_menu_item)"
No need to store any variable.

Comment: view binding doesn't work with toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

**If your menu inside NavigationView**
example:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView 
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_layout" />
```

**then you can find your menu item by id like this**

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id);
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of another answer and is at risk of being down voted.  To avoid that, either explain why it is different or delete it.